# Upload files while user is filling form

Tags: node.js, html, forms, server-side

I am creating a form where users can post an ad including photos. Its not necessary for a user to login/register before accessing this form. I need to upload photos asynchronously while user is filling the form. (for example, gumtree.com.au lets you upload photos while you are creating a new ad)

I know we can start uploading files as soon the user selects the files. However, on server side how would it be possible to identify those files later when the user submits form? How to handle the uploaded files if the user abandons unfilled form?

What is a typical design pattern to achieve this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one approach

**Part 1**

when a user visits your site it contacts the server and sends a random generated 10  alphanumeric characters e.g (Xf4ht5Y4u9). This is the users identifier code

can be easyly achieved with a bit of javascript and ajax on the client side

on the server side you can use PHP to create a temporary directory named with the users identifier code

**Part 2**

user uploads files and sends them asynchronously to this temporary folder

**Part 3**

user fills in the form = **true** --- perform actions e.g process form and images, move them from the temp folder. the temp folder is now empty. it can be used for the next batch of uploads if you want that functionally. you can wait for the upload success callback just in case files are still uploading

user fills in the form = **false** --- the uploaded files stay in the temp folder because they haven't been processed.

**Part 4**

server side house keeping. check temp folders once a day if older than x amount of days from current date and delete them to save space. can be done with a shell script on any platform

If you are worried how long unprocessed files are kept hanging around on the server then change the logic of the above. e.g run house keeping every hour and check if temp folder age is > than 6 hours or whatever

In the unlikely event a user uploads files now and in 6 hours fills in the form then on the server side you can report back to the client to say that the files have been deleted and they need to upload them again. but this all depends if space is an issue.

you could auto open a popup window after 5 hours to say that the uploaded files will be deleted soon as they haven't filled in the form yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was waiting for other answers with alternative solutions before accepting your answer

Comment: @Khalid Amin -- no problem. as i mentioned in the A, this is one of a few solutions and there are bits and pieces in the parts that need to  be expanded, however in a nutshell this approach should work ok